# test variable values according to their labels in data frame

Tags: r

I need to clean data in a way that all values are within the given labels range. Labels have been set in SPSS, I use *haven* package to import them to R.
I extract the labels with:

```
as.numeric(attr(data[[var]], "labels"))
```

giving me a vector of the numbers. Now I iterate over the dataframe with the goal of saving all variablenames of variables that contain values outside of this range to get an Idea of the amount of cases. Lateron I might automatically replace these values with a certain missing code (e.g. -3).

```
for (var in names(data)) {
  legalLabels <- as.numeric(attr(data[[var]], "labels"))
  if (!any(data[[var]] %in% legalLabels)) {
    result <- c(result, var)
  }
}
```

The *result* vector now only contains character variables, numerical (or double/integer) variables are neglected.

I also tried:

```
if (any(data[[var]] < min(legalLabels)) || any(data[[var]] > max(legalLabels))) {...}
```

without success. The labels (by that I mean numbers coding the answer) usually are -4 to -1 for missing categories and positive numbers from 0 to 10, depending on the respective variable / number of answers.

## EDIT MWE:

```
library("haven")
library("dplyr")
var1 <- labelled(c(1,1,-2,-1,2), c(NonResponse = -1, SystemMiss = -2, Yes = 1, No = 2), label="Test Variable 1")
var2 <- labelled(c(-1,2,-2,1,3), c(NonResponse = -1, SystemMiss = -2, Yes = 1, No = 2), label="Test Variable 2")

testdata <- data.frame(var1, var2)

result <- NULL
for (var in names(testdata)) {
  legalLabels <- as.numeric(attr(testdata[[var]], "labels")) # legalLabels => [1] -1 -2  1  2
  if (!any(data[[var]] %in% legalLabels)) {
    result <- c(result, var)
  }
}

>result
[1] "var1" "var2"

result should only include var2 since it contains a '3'
```

Comment: Hello, can you please give a MWE, with dummy data?

Comment: done, although I have the feeling that labels that were set in SPSS behave slightly different.

Comment: Isn't it only a logical issue? Try replacing the "if" line with this:   if (sum(!testdata[[var]] %in% legalLabels)) {

Comment: Doesn't work, still way too many variables in _result_. I found a very inefficient workaround (which also works with the _any_ logic) so thats okay for now, but I am sure that there must be a much much easier approach to this. Thx for trying tho

Answer (score 1):

What I came up with:

```
# only consider numerical variables
numData <- data %>% select_if(is.numeric)

# fill list with legal values corresponding to each respective variable
legalValues.lst <- list() # list of legal labels for each variable in df
counter <- 0
for (var in names(numData)) {
  legalValues <- as.numeric(attr(data[[var]], "labels"))
  legalValues <- c(legalValues, NA)  # always add NA as legal entry
  print(legalValues)
  counter <- counter + 1
  print(counter)
  legalValues.lst[counter] <- list(legalValues)
}

# compare variable values to the corresponding vector of legal values from list above
counter <- 0
for (var in names(numData)) {
  counter <- counter + 1
  
  tempVec <- NULL
  tempVec <- legalValues.lst[[counter]]
  
  print(var)
  print(any(!numData[[var]] %in% tempVec)) 
}

# prints all variable names and TRUE, if any value in that variable is NOT in the corresponding list entry of legal labels
#                               FALSE otherwise
# Narrows down variables that need to be looked into
```